# How to determine the time-complexity of a simple palindrome R code?

Tags: r, time-complexity, big-o

I am pretty new to calculating time-complexity of an algorithm or a code, so I'm not sure what will be the complexity of this next function:

```
isPalindrome <- function(num){
  if(num < 0) return(F)
  rev <- 0
  orig_num <- num
  while(num != 0){
    pop <- num %% 10
    num <- num %/% 10
    rev <- rev*10 + pop
  }
  if(orig_num == rev) return(T)
  else return(F)
}
```

And calling the function, e.g. `isPalindrome(122221)` will return `TRUE`.
The basic idea is that a reverse number is being calculated and then compared against the original number, if they are equal then it is a palindrome.

My basic intuition was that in order to calculate the reverse number the `while` loop will go through every digit, so e.g for a 4 digit number like `1221` there will be 4 actions to be made (with some execution time to complete each), and so if my number becomes 2 times larger with respect to its digits, e.g `12222221` then I will need 8 actions to be made. Then, my input grew by 2 and time also grew by 2, so the time-complexity should be `O(n)`. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is simply O(n) - there's one loop, which goes through the digits of the number, so it's O(n) with respect to the number of digits. It's O(floor(log10(n)) + 1) with respect to the input number, though. So it depends on what you want to measure it with respect to.

Comment: @Suren: Why, what for?

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi: That's exactly it, I want to measure it against my input which is a number eventually, can you explain why is this a O(floor(log10(n)) + 1)? The number is essentially made from digits, so how can these two differ in complexity time?

Comment: I meant to say you can easily check if a number is a palindrome by converting it to a character. I wasn't commenting on the time complexity.

Comment: `O(floor(log10(n)) + 1)` is the digit-counting function: we take the `log10` of the number (i.e find x where 10^x=n) - e.g `log10(10) = 1`, `log10(100) = 2`, `log10(1) = 1`, `log10(7) = 0.845...` . We then floor it, because the number of digits in, say, 14 (`log10(14)=1.146`) and 11 (`log10(11)=1.041`) are the same. As you can see, the digit count is shifted 1 too low, now, because we're measuring with respect to 10. So, we add one on top get the digit count. Since it's an O(digits) loop, we can just plug in `floor(log10(n))+1` to get the final big O relative to the input number.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right: your algorithm will run in `O(n)` with respect to the digits of the number. That is to say, comparing it to the size of the number, an `O(floor(log10(n)) + 1)`, which is is the number-counting function.